# Flutter - RichText Editor with Image and Video upload

Tags: flutter, dart, editor, flutter-dependencies, richtext

There is requirement in my project that user can upload images and videos with text inline like rich text editor. I have tried zefyr and flutter quill package but there is no option of video upload in them.
Can anyone suggest how can i achieve this requirement?

Thanks